# Mongoose count certain element in an embedded documents array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am using [mongoose 4.6.3](http://mongoosejs.com/).

I have the following schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./User');

var TicketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
},
{
    timestamps: true
});

var DrawSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  max_ticket_per_user : { type : Number, required: true },
  tickets: [TicketSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Draw', DrawSchema);
```

How can I count the embedded documents of a certain User ObjectId(user field in TicketSchema) in a Draw's tickets(tickets field in DrawSchema) ?
I want to count the tickets of a user for a single draw.

Would it be better to change my schema design ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework taking advantage of the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** and **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operators to get the filtered array with elements that match the user id and its size respectively which will subsequently give you the count.

For an single draw, consider adding a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline operator as your initial step with the _id query to filter the documents in the collection.

Consider running the following aggregation pipeline to get the desired result:

```
Draw.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": drawId } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "ticketsCount": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$tickets",
                        "as": "item",
                        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$item.user", userId ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Great answer. I get the information I need but I only want to aggregate on a draw with a given id.

Comment: what I get as a response is all the draws id with their count for the userId. I only want to aggregate on a single draw id

Comment: @AlexB You'd need a $match pipeline query to filter your documents, as I've shown in the update above.

Comment: FWIW, Most cloud based Mongodb platforms, such as every cloud based solution provided by Heroku, doesn't support mongo version `3.4` yet, and hence the `$filter` command won't work

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `.count()` deep parameters like any other query object:

```
Draw.count({'tickets.user._id' : userId}, console.log);
```

Make sure the userId variable is an ObjectId.  If it's a string, do this:

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
let userId = new ObjectId(incomingStringId);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for a specific draw. I will try adding "_id" : drawId